# Recyclerview - Wrong position arrayList into onBindViewHolder

Tags: android

I have a "ArrayList" to enumerate the data, but when I try get the data in my onBindViewHolder I get a position incorrect with scroll up / down

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CAPusheenAdapter_Fragment_0_3.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        CustomItem_0_ALL pusheen = pusheenArrayList.get(position);

for(int i=0;i<pusheen.getAllStrings().size();i++){
            // correct data
           /*viewHolder.allTextViews.get(0).setText("melón");
           viewHolder.allTextViews.get(1).setText("melón");
           viewHolder.allTextViews.get(2).setText("melón");
           viewHolder.allTextViews.get(3).setText("melón");
           viewHolder.allTextViews.get(4).setText("melón");*/
           // random position 
            viewHolder.allTextViews.get(i).setText("melón");

        }
```

**Note Edited 29/03/2016 11:42 : public ArrayList< TextView >     allTextViews;

I can't understand why, I try  setHasStableIds(true); but nothing.

Any idea ?

If not I will comment directly to google.

I found problem :

```
03-29 06:03:08.683 11716-11716/com.xx.aplicacion D/-POSITIONS CURRENTS->: 0 _____> com.xx.aplicacion.Adapters.CustomItem_0_ALL@b0bcdf8
03-29 06:03:08.686 11716-11716/com.xx.aplicacion D/-POSITIONS CURRENTS->: 1 _____> com.xx.aplicacion.Adapters.CustomItem_0_ALL@c8ac136
03-29 06:03:08.692 11716-11716/com.xx.aplicacion D/-POSITIONS CURRENTS->: 2 _____> com.xx.aplicacion.Adapters.CustomItem_0_ALL@12bd1a4
03-29 06:03:10.549 11716-11716/com.xx.aplicacion D/-POSITIONS CURRENTS->: 3 _____> com.xx.aplicacion.Adapters.CustomItem_0_ALL@cb9bac2
03-29 06:03:10.582 11716-11716/com.xx.aplicacion D/-POSITIONS CURRENTS->: 4 _____> com.xx.aplicacion.Adapters.CustomItem_0_ALL@9266410
03-29 06:03:10.599 11716-11716/com.xx.aplicacion D/-POSITIONS CURRENTS->: 5 _____> com.xx.aplicacion.Adapters.CustomItem_0_ALL@eecc10e
03-29 06:03:10.628 11716-11716/com.xx.aplicacion D/-POSITIONS CURRENTS->: 6 _____> com.xx.aplicacion.Adapters.CustomItem_0_ALL@5f5b13c
03-29 06:03:13.105 11716-11716/com.xx.aplicacion D/-POSITIONS CURRENTS->: 2 _____> com.xx.aplicacion.Adapters.CustomItem_0_ALL@12bd1a4
03-29 06:03:13.145 11716-11716/com.xx.aplicacion D/-POSITIONS CURRENTS->: 1 _____> com.xx.aplicacion.Adapters.CustomItem_0_ALL@c8ac136
03-29 06:03:13.178 11716-11716/com.xx.aplicacion D/-POSITIONS CURRENTS->: 0 _____> com.xx.aplicacion.Adapters.CustomItem_0_ALL@b0bcdf8
```

you will get a errors with try get a data because, the list not is the same to up and down

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of the Recycler Adapter:

```
    ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    itemList.add(new FruitItem("Melon"));
```

And in the Item:

```
public class FruitItem extends Item {
    private String fruit;

    public FruitItem(String fruit) {
        super();
        this.fruit = fruit;
    }
    @Override
    public void bindToViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewholder) {
        FruitViewHolder holder = (FruitViewHolder) viewholder;
        holder.title.setText(fruit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but is more complex, I have  viewHolder.allTextViews is  ArrayList<TextView>  with getIdentifier, in your case  holder.allTextViews(0) returns in your case holder.title

Comment: You shouldn't save your TextViews in a ArrayList. Items will be reused in a RecyclerView. With other words, your TextViews are reused to improve the performance. When an items leaves the screen is will be reused on the other side of the screen. Try to make RecyclerView Adapter like this example: http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: you can use, is other concept, I know, but if use a index static 0-4 0-1000, Works correctly, but if you use position from onBindViewHolder to cast object or the same position to iterate not Works correctly